# jQuery color picker recommendation

Tags: javascript, jquery, color-picker

I need jquery color picker plugin that is very light, and that lets the user drag the mouse over a colorwheel and has the ability to select transparent color (or "blank/none").

Any suggestions?

Comment: did you try this http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the below good link from google, see if these are useful:

http://komunitasweb.com/2009/09/3-amazing-jquery-color-picker-plugins/

Comment: thanks, jcolorpicker seems the only one with a transparent color option

Comment: @kobe: Please stop with the "did you try google" answers. Many times, SO is the top result on google anyway. People come here to get recommendations & advice from experienced coders, not some unqualified link. Your answer would have been great without that.

Comment: @Hollister sure , i won't do it again. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: And... the link is broken.

Comment: [This one](https://github.com/tovic/color-picker) is pure JavaScript and the [wiki](https://github.com/tovic/color-picker/wiki/jQuery-Plugin) just give you some tips on how to create a jQuery plugin with it.

Answer (score 1):

after lots of searching, I found colorPicker the best one in terms of performance and options, so I strongly recommend it 
http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/