# jquery Colorpicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, color-picker

I am new to jquery.

I did come across http://komunitasweb.com/2009/09/3-amazing-jquery-color-picker-plugins/ but these plugins are to much for me. I want a color picker with only 3 tiny sliders which change a div box. No extra colored field. Only `R,G,B`?

I also did read [jQuery color picker recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4424368/jquery-color-picker-recommendation) :)

Is there something out there or possible with one of these tools to make it littler?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [this jQuery UI Colorpicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#colorpicker) out of the demo.